# Can I hold incoming sk_buffs for some time?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, network-programming

I need to store several MBs of incoming traffic in a buffer inside the kernel for some deferred non-realtime processing. Since I operate high bitrate streams (3Gb/s) I cannot afford copying the data directly. Can I just hold some incoming sk_buffs (without releasing them up to some moment)? Should I increase size of the sk_buff pool then?

Comment: Take it you're using `netfilter`? How about buffering `sk_buffs` and spinning a `kthread` which takes elements from that buffer and puts them away, e.g. write to disk.

Comment: I receive skbs in a handler added by `dev_add_pack()`.

Comment: Is this as IP packet you are handling ? Function you are using seems to be for adding a new packet type based on ethertype of the packet. Do you have a different ethertype for your packets ?

Comment: Yes, regular IP/IPv6 packets.

Comment: Did you find out? Also still wondering, is kthread + wait queues not an option?

Comment: @ababo Do you really need to add a new packet type function if you are using standard IP packets ? You should be able to create a netfilter module and attach it on PREROUTING Hook. Then you need to add a queue of skbs in your netfilter modules and a kernel timer to dequeue from the queue. You should be able to use NF_STOLEN to tell the stack that this netfilter module of yours now owns the skb ( i.e. you need to eventually call skb_free).

Comment: You _could_ even use NFLOG and pass interesting packets to user-space over netlink and have ulogd process them ( or your user-space equivalent) if you do not like the kernel module idea...